# unknown display second monitor stays black and periodically flashes

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors

Hello I am having a problem with my dual monitor set-up my primary screen works good but my second screen stays black and periodically flashes (less than a second)
[Ubuntu display setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxThS.png)

Both displays are connected to my gtx 1050 ti graphics card my primary is connected by hdmi and my secondary is connected through dvi-d.

NVIDIA recognizes the device name but the screen remains black here is a photo of my NVIDIA [Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SveNe.png)

I thought maybe it was a driver problem but it seems like I am using the correct [Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOVeq.png)

Any help is appreciated, I am still fairly new to [Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4XVI.png)

Things I have tried

1: rebooted pc

2:sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

3:unplugged monitor and then replugged it back in

(also would like to say that this dual monitor set-up worked for 1 day before the screen turned black after a reboot)

Comment: Try reducing the frequency in incremental steps.

Comment: I tried changing the refresh rate in incremental steps but nothing changed I believe that's what you were suggesting.